# Выбор точки реализации метода в связных данных

Tags: php

Есть связные данные многие-многие, многие-один. 
1) Многие-один. Комментарии и статьи. У них есть соответствующие сервисы для работы с ними. Из какого сервиса получать комментарии определенной статьи?

`ArticleService::getArticleComments($articleId)`  или `CommentService::getByArticleId($articleId)` ?

2) Многие-Многие. Вопрос аналогичный. Сущности Книги и Жанры.

```
 $books = Genre::getGenreBooks($genreid);
 $genres = Book::getBookGenres($bookid);
```

или

```
$genre = Genre::getbyBook($bookId);
$books = Book::getbyGenre($genreId);
```

Comment: `$article = $articleService->get($articleId); $comments = $article->getComments();`

Comment: Разве этот вариант не будет ровно на 1 запрос больше?

Comment: Если вы оперируете сущностями, а не таблицами, строками и столбцами, то это нормально. Но всё же если это не ваш путь, то правильнее будет `CommentService::getByArticleId($articleId)` потому что вы получаете комментарии, а не статьи. Ну если быть ещё точнее, то лучше назвать `CommentDao`